# Can we modify the highlighted questions color?

Tags: discussion, site-design, tagging

I found pretty difficult to distinguish between an highlighted and a non-highlighted question on the Arduino site. Is it just me?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately we can't change that. All Stack Exchange sites use the same design during their beta phase. If/when we graduate to a full site, we'll get a custom design.

With that said, the difference between highlighted and non-highlighted seems reasonably clear to me. Perhaps you need to adjust some display settings on your system?

Alternatively, you could use a browser add-on which lets you write a script to modify the design automatically on-the-fly (e.g. GreaseMonkey).

Comment: I don't know, maybe I'm too used to the Stack Overflow bright orange. Thank you for the info btw.